# POST request with R and x-www-form-urlencoded fails encoding Payload

Tags: r, api, post

I am trying to obtain some response from an API after POST request.

From REST I can easily access and obtain desired data. 
From R I am having problems sending the payload to the server.

This is the code in R:

```
query <- list(token = mytoken,
              module = "TeleMesura",
              class = "TeleMesuras",
              action = action,
              data = mydata)

  response <- POST(url = myurl,
                 body = query,
                 encode = "form", 
                 verbose(),
                 add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form- 
  urlencoded"))
```

The problem is in `"mydata"` and how it is encoded by R to be sent to the server. The original data parameter of the body as introduced in REST is:

```
{"cups" : "ES0XXXXXXXXXXX", "initDate" : "2018-01-03" , "endDate" : "2018-01-03" }
```

To obtain this "string" in R i have to force it as:

```
data_hard <- paste("{",dQuote("cups"), " : ",dQuote(CUP),", ",
                  dQuote("initDate")," : ",dQuote(as.character(date_start))," , ",
                  dQuote("endDate")," : ",dQuote(as.character(date_end))," }", sep = "")
```

Which yields:

```
"{“cups” : “ES0XXXXXXXXXXD”, “initDate” : “2018-01-03” , “endDate” : “2018-01-03” }"
```

REST encodes it as:

```
*%7B%22cups%22+%3A+%22ES0XXXXXXXXXXX%22%2C+%22initDate%22+%3A+%222018-01-03%22+%2C+%22endDate%22+%3A+%222018-01-03%22+%7D*
```

While R sends to the server (obtained thanks to verbose() )

```
*%7B%E2%80%9Ccups%E2%80%9D%20%3A%20%E2%80%9CESXXXXXXXXXXD%E2%80%9D%2C%20%E2%80%9CinitDate%E2%80%9D%20%3A%20%E2%80%9C2018-01-03%E2%80%9D%20%2C%20%E2%80%9CendDate%E2%80%9D%20%3A%20%E2%80%9C2018-01-03%E2%80%9D%20%7D*
```

I attach two screenshots from REST client at the end.

Could please help me introducing properly this data parameter in the body? I have tried with jsonlite and serializeJSON but not success. Trying to access through application/json have failed from REST so I would like to avoid this option. THANKS!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try not using `dquote`. This looks like you are trying to post JSON data so use a proper JSON encoder like `mydata
 <- jsonlite::toJSON(list("cups" = "ES0XXXXXXXXXXX", "initDate" = "2018-01-03" , "endDate" = "2018-01-03"), auto_unbox = TRUE)`.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick!!!

I tried before but as is my first time with Json i messed up with serializingJSON. 

This has solved the problem and now the request is sent to the server perfectly.